# WP API in React Js (Gutenberg Editor) : Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined even with condition

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've built a dynamic block in Gutenberg editor for latest custom posts.

And fetched featuredmedia for them through _embed.
So it's working if all my posts have featured image, but if not I have an error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'wp:featuredmedia' of undefined
```

So I made condition, but having the same error.
What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@wordpress/element';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { withSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

class PortfolioPostsEdit extends Component {
    render() {
        const { posts, className } = this.props;
        return (
            <>
                {(posts && posts.length > 0) ?
                    <div className={className}>
                        {posts.map(post => (
                            <article key={post.id}>
                                <a href={post.link}>
                                    {post.title.rendered}
                                </a>
                                {post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] &&
                                    <div className="image">
                                        <img src={post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'[0].source_url} />  
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </article>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                : <div>{__("No Posts Found", "my-blocks")}</div>
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withSelect(
    (select, props) => {
        return {
            posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'my_portfolio', 'per_page: 20', '_embed: true')
        }
    }
)(PortfolioPostsEdit);
```

I can't understand why my condition doesn't work:

```
{post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] &&
    <div className="image">
        <img src={post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'[0].source_url} />  
    </div>
}
```

Can someone help me, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mean `post._embedded` is undefined. Try this:

```
post && post._embedded && post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] // make sure post._embedded is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!!!! worked great for me, I was puzzled with this for several days....

this is my working code for validating post contain feature image so I wont get any error in case we try to load a post that don't have  a feature image set.

**post && post._embedded && post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']&&**

```
{posts && posts.length > 0 ? (
        <ul className={className}>
            {posts.map(post => (
                <li key={post.id}>
                    <a
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        href={post.link}
                    >
                        {decodeEntities(post.title.rendered)}
                    </a>

                    {
```

**post && post._embedded && post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']&&**

```
                    <>
                    <img src={post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url}/>
                    <span>{post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].title.rendered}</span>
                    </>
                    }


                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    ) : (
        <div>
            {" "}
            {posts
                ? __("No Posts Found", "mytheme-blocks")
                : __("Loading...", "mytheme-blocks")}{" "}
        </div>
    )}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30487130)

Comment: please have another look....
My code is a bit different' it was base on the code in the answer and that is why i have posted my code.
my: 
post && post._embedded && post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']&&

original:
post && post._embedded && post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']